# Center <div> vertically within another <div>

Tags: html, css

I am trying to setup something that looks like this with the arrow that is centered vertically:

[image]

CSS:

```css
#arrowdiv {
    width:282px;
    height:61px;
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/RV80I.png');
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#optin {
    height:110px;
    width:960px;
    background-color:#FFFFBF;
    border:1px solid black;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
    margin: 0 auto;
} 

#leftdiv {
    width:340px;
    height:108px;
}
```

​
HTML:

```
<div id="optin">
    <div id="leftdiv">
        <div id="arrowdiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NzMLd/1/

Right now, it is only centered horizontally, as you can see in my jsFiddle.

Comment: i have been trying different things man, i cant get it to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `background-` settings:

```
#arrowdiv {
    width:282px;
    height:61px;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/RV80I.png);
    background-position: 0 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/NzMLd/3/

Comment: thank you for showing me this. i have been trying to do ultra complex ways i have been finding on google and the other related ones have all been much more complex than this. much appreeciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have fixed height of different DIVs, you can add this to your arrow:

```
margin-top:23px;
```

where 23=(108-61)/2

And yes, an alternative method is to use this

```
background-position: 0 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tons of ways to do this... Your fiddle isn't working for me for some reason, but try this as your `leftdiv` CSS:

```
#leftdiv {
    width:340px;
    height:108px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```